# Updating same column twice while joining with another table is not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-update, left-join, mariadb-10.3

Consider I have two tables, `t1` and `t2`.  `t1` has two columns: `c1` and `c2`. `t2` has two columns: `c1` and `c3`. We insert values in both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT, c2 INT);
CREATE TABLE t2 (c1 int, c3 int);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (10,10), (20,20);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (10,10), (20,20);
```

Updating `t1` with this query:

```
update t1 
set c2 = c2 + 10,
    c2 = c2 + 20
```

will yield the next result: `c2` column will respectively be equal to 40,50. This means, the first update was evaluated and then the next update used the first update value, so it's like using `c2 = c2 + 10 + 20`.

Considering I need to update `t1` again, but this time, joining with `t2` table, using this query:

```
update t1 left join t2 using (c1)
set c2 = c2+10,
    c2 = c2+20;
```

This query will yield the next result: `c2` column will respectively be equal to 60,70, which means, the first update was ignored, and only the `c2 = c2+20` was being evaluated at the end. I was expecting the results to be 70,80.

[Here's a working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=101ab59674f70e5287dc63b273de2528)

I know that I didn't use `t2` in the join, but in my real example I need to use `t2` and I need to update same column twice, using the first update value.

Why does the same update with join yield different result, and is it possible to make it work without splitting the update into two separate updates?

**EDIT**: I've been told that the same code used to work on MariaDB 10.1, but after upgrading to 10.3 it failed. (Unfortunately, I can't find an online MariaDB 10.1 fiddle to test it myself)

Comment: "I need to update the same column twice".  I've done a lot of work with databases and I've never had to do that.   I think there are probably better (or at least alternative) solutions for what you want to do.  Note:  I would expect your query to either return an error or to only use one of the expressions for the `update`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Splitting the updates in two consecutive ones is an option. This is not my code. I just identified the problem for a friend and asked about it to be able to reply with some insights from more experienced users on SO. It's not throwing an error, in fact, it's just using the second update. It's weird for me why would it work without a join, but with a join it only uses one of the `set`

Comment: . . In the SQL standard, a `SET` uses values from the "before" table on the right hand side.  No accumulation is possible.   MySQL/MariaDB do not implement this functionality, but I certainly would not depend on such bespoke behavior (which is barely documented).

Comment: In MySql the behavior you expect is consistent: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dadc55747c741483410a32fc837b999b

Comment: @forpas It seems that it's something to do between MariaDB 10.1 and 10.3.